# Combine all data in to single by seperating in to commas

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    FACT.Id fActivityId, FACT.ActivityName,
    ACT.fOrganizationRegion_Id, ACT.Id AS ActivityId, ACT.CreateUserId,
    (US.LastName + ',' +US.FirstName) AS UserName,
    REG.Id AS RegionId, REG.OrganizationName AS RegionName,
    ORG.Id AS OrganizationId, ORG.OrganizationName AS OrganizationName,
    FC.Id AS FundingSourceId, fc.FundingSource,
    CA.Id AS CoverageAreaId, CA.County, CA.ZipCode
FROM 
    Activities ACT
JOIN 
    fActivity FACT ON FACT.Id = ACT.fActivity_Id
JOIN
    fOrganizationRegion ORGREG ON ORGREG.Id = ACT.fOrganizationRegion_Id
JOIN 
    fOrganization REG ON REG.Id = ORGREG.RegionOrg_Id
JOIN 
    fOrganization ORG ON ORG.Id = ORGREG.Org_Id
JOIN 
    ActivityFundingSource AFC ON AFC.Activity_Id = ACT.Id
JOIN 
    fFundingSource FC ON FC.Id = AFC.FundingSource_Id
JOIN 
    ActivityCoverageArea ACA ON ACA.Activity_Id = ACT.Id
JOIN 
    fCoverageAreas CA ON CA.Id = ACA.CoverageArea_Id
JOIN 
    Users US ON US.UserId  = ACT.CreateUserId
LEFT JOIN 
    fInterventionType ITYPE ON ITYPE.Id = FACT.InterventionType_Id
LEFT JOIN 
    ActivityInterveningVariable AIVAR ON AIVAR.Activity_Id = ACT.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    fInterveningVariables IVAR ON IVAR.Id = AIVAR.fInterveningVariable_Id
LEFT JOIN 
    ActivitySecondaryPriorityProblem ASPP ON ASPP.Activity_Id = ACT.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    fPriorityProblem PP ON PP.Id = ASPP.fPriorityProblem_Id
LEFT JOIN 
    fMethodApproach MA ON MA.Id = ACT.fMethodApproach_Id
LEFT JOIN 
    fStrategyMethodApproach  SMA ON SMA.fMethodApproach_Id = MA.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    fStrategy ST ON ST.Id = SMA.fStrategy_Id
LEFT JOIN 
    ActivityTargetPopulation ATP ON ATP.Activity_Id = ACT.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    fTargetPopulation TP ON TP.Id = ATP.TargetPopulation_Id
```

My result set is as below screen shot

[image]

my question is i want to club all records based on ActivityId , highlited in Red as single record.

[image]

Comment: I have 20/15 vision and can't read that image

Comment: Images of code and data is not a good approach. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) And something resembling desired output would make this a LOT better. At current, it is just guesswork.

Comment: Depending on your version of SQL server, there are a number of ways you can concatenate strings... Most commonly, using either `STRING_AGG` or STUFF FOR XML PATH

Comment: Needs moar joins

Comment: And by that I mean, maybe, start with a simpler example...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
select 
    activityID, 
    string_agg(country,',') as country, 
    string_agg(cast(zipcode as varchar(10)),',') as Zipcode
from YourTableName
group by activityID
```

- You must have SQL server 2017 or above
- `string_agg` only works with string

Comment: [Please don't ever cast anything as `varchar` without specifying a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: I do it all the time.  What is the problem with it?